# Is it correct to say VI that contains Uninitialized Shift Register will never be removed from memory?

Tags: labview

VI will be removed from memory if its reference is closed, finished execution, etc...
The consequence of that are the removal of resources refnums,... due to automatic garbage collection.

It seems that VIs with uninitialized SRs are not removed from memory, so I can store refnums in this VI as TOP LEVEL vi and they are always alive (even though its callers are closed but not the labview environment). Is it correct ?

Answer (score 1):

The rule for most references which you open explicitly is that the reference will be automatically closed when the hierarchy that the reference was created in goes idle. The hierarchy is determined by the top-level VI, so if VI A calls VI B and VI B obtains a new queue reference, that reference will be automatically closed when VI A stops running.

Note that this doesn't affect the actual refnum itself (which is simply a 32 bit value), but rather the validity of that reference with the API which uses it. That means that if you open a reference from hierarchy A and keep it in a SR in VI B, which is shared with hierarchy C, and you then close hierarchy A, the value in the SR will still be there, but you won't be able to use it.

Also note that opening a reference to a VI programmatically and running it will make that VI a top-level VI.